# passing url parameters in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to pass some url parameter between view to get the detail of a particular user but i'm finding it hard to do

below is the js and html

```
    .controller('profile_detail_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$state',function($scope,$http,$state){
    $http.get('http://localhost/myapp/app_ion/templates/profile/profile.php?profile_id='+$scope.profile_detail).success(function(data){
           $scope.profile_detail=data;
           $scope.profile_id=$state.params.profile_id;

       });

 //pass profile_id to view detail of a user bound to 'profile_detail_ctrl' controller

     .state('tabs.detail',{
        url:'/source/:profile_id',
        views:{
        'list-source':{
        templateUrl:  'templates/profile/profile.html', 
        controller: 'profile_detail_ctrl'


        } 
        }
    })
```

HTML

```
<ion-item href="#/tab/source/{{item.profile_id}}">
 <div class="item item-avatar">
<img src="../usr_up_img/{{item.profile_pix}}">
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <p>November 05, 1955</p>
  </div>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
```

When a user clicks on the link `"href"`. it should navigate to the page which contains the details of the user

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Service?

Comment: It's not obvious what your problem is based on the code you presented.  However, I might question the logic here;  If you have `$scope.profile_detail` already set (in order to append it to the end of your URL), why would you then set it to the `data` returned from the `get` request?

Comment: As far i can deduct from your question you are trying to pass url parameter from another page or controller to your profile_detail_ctrl right??. You need to mention from where you want to pass the param as well. I got lazy to answer the question because, the question itself is not clear.

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked, i've editted the question and has the full script of the js and html

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked, i've editted the question and has the full script of the js and html

Comment: @neiza you are making mistake in your get call. check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can deduct from your code, you are making mistake in retrieving the data. You need to send your profile_id which comes from `$stateParams` as follows.

```
.controller('profile_detail_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$state','$stateParams',function($scope,$http,$state,$stateParams){
    $http.get('http://localhost/myapp/app_ion/templates/profile/profile.php?profile_id='+$stateParams.profile_id).success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.profile_detail=data;
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code

```
$http({
url: 'http://localhost/myapp/app_ion/templates/profile/profile.php', 
method: "GET",
params: {profile_id: $state.params.profile_id}}).success(function (data) {
      $scope.profile_detail=data;

 });
```